# Jquery Mobile NO_FAST_DRAW = FALSE

Tags: cordova, jquery-mobile

I'm developing an application for JQM 1.3 with Phonegap 2.5 over ICS 4.0.4.

I'm showing some dynamical listviews about 50 items that produces scroll in html page.
When I do a click/tap on a non-scrolled item the event triggers well, but when I scroll the page and do the same the event doesn't trigger until I scroll top the page.

In every click/tap I have the same message:

```
04-16 17:53:02.843: V/webview(31651): NO_FAST_DRAW = false
04-16 17:53:03.656: V/webview(31651):  singleCursorHandlerTouchEvent -getEditableSupport FASLE
```

I've tried some solutions from this forum but nothing!

Please help...

Thanks

Comment: It seems if I change touchend event by tap event, it works better but not fine! Sometimes, when I scroll the page, I have to tap twice for trigger the event. Weird...